# Excel interprets date entered differently among many users

Tags: excel

I have a file with columns configured to format dates as yyyy/mm/dd. It's a shared file with a small team. Whenever I type "January 13" in a cell in the column, it returns a value of 2018/01/13, which is what the team wants. However, when my  other colleagues enter the same "January 13" in that column, it returns a 2013/01/01 value. It's like Excel is interpreting the "13" as the year on his/her unit. We all use the same 2013 version and same computer model/type/brand.

What we tried so far:

```
-Comparing Excel applications to ensure the same configurations
-Saving the file as .xlsx instead of .xls
-Redoing the sheet into a new one
-Closing and opening the sheet
```

Yet none still worked. We hope to not go on the option of typing the whole date (January 13, 2018) as we somehow our fingers are dexterously trained to typing just January 13. Any insights on this please? Thanks! :)

Comment: Just a guess but I would check whether the default date formats / internationalisation settings in Windows are the same on each computer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the Windows Regional Short Date settings.

If the short date settings are a variation of MDY, Excel will interpret your input(spelled out month and digits) as **MD**

If the short date settings are a variation of DMY; Excel will interpret your input as **MY**

In both cases, the Month is unambiguous. The short date format then interprets the digit based on the token following the Month token.

You will also see different results if you enter dates such as 1-12 vs 1-13 in the different environments.

If changing the short date settings is not an option (and the settings involved are MDY and DMY), one fix would be to always enter the dates as `dd mmmm  (13 January)` as that would be interpreted as `Jan 13, current year`  in either environment.

Answer (score -1):

I would select all the cells/rows/columns that have dates and customize the format. Go to Home>Number and click on the dropdown (it might say "General" or "Short Date" or something). Click on "More Number Formats" and go to "Custom". In the cell under "Type:" put yyyy/mm/dd . Any way you type the date it should come out the same now. Either way, typing in number format should be easier than typing the month name.

Comment: the question appears to suggest that this has already been done. The issue is with how Excel interprets dates typed in other formats, not how it displays them.